# Steps for getting correct Texture

Tags: texturing, materials

I am pretty new to Blender and I have done my first model of a bumper plate (for weight lifting. Now I should apply texture to it to look like picture below. Now how do I do that? I have tried unwrapping some similar material images but could not get the exact look.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Hi there : ) .Can you add an image of what you got and explain a bit more on what you want to achieve?

Comment: you could either try to use your this image in an Image Texture, or recreate this kind of material procedurally, these are 2 different ways, you need to precise which one you're interested in

Comment: Let say I want to recreate that kind of material, I tried using some concrete like pavement textures and and made them black but the it did not turn out well :(